# Dense in the special unitary group

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

I was going through the [PhD thesis](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2117) of Daniel Nagaj. In the last paragraph on page 30, there is this following sentence.

> A universal gate set must be dense in the group $SU(n)\ldots$

My question is what does 'dense' mean when it is about a special unitary group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $SU(n)$ of unitary $n\times n$ matrices with determinant $1$ can be viewed as a subset of $\Bbb{C}^{n^2}$, in the way that the set of all $n\times n$ matrices can be viewed as *all* of $\Bbb{C}^{n^2}$. Since $\Bbb{C}$ has a topology, $SU(n)$ inherits this topology when we interpret $SU(n)\subseteq\Bbb{C}^{n^2}$, so it makes sense to talk about a subset of $SU(n)$ being dense in $SU(n)$: it means that when thought of as a subset $S\subseteq\Bbb{C}^{n^2}$, $\overline{S} = SU(n)$ - which is exactly what it means to be dense normally. We simply need to interpret the first entry of a matrix $M\in SU(n)$ as the first coordinate of a vector in $\Bbb{C}^{n^2}$, the entry in the first row and the second column as the second entry of a vector in $\Bbb{C}^{n^2}$ (with the standard basis, of course), and so on, to be able to talk about a topology on $SU(n)$, whence it becomes natural to talk about denseness, openness, closedness, or any topological property of $SU(n)$ or a subset thereof.

Comment: could you please explain:                             1. What did you mean by $\Bbb{C}$ has a topology?        2. Let's take the case of $SU(2)$. According to the Wikipedia page it is defined as follows: $$ SU(2) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha -\bar{\beta} \\ 
\beta \bar{\alpha}
\end{pmatrix} : \alpha , \beta \in {\bf C}, | \alpha |^2  + | \beta |^2 = 1 \right\}$$. Now it is a subset of $ \Bbb{C}^{2^2} = \Bbb{C}^{4}$. Let's take a matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \in SU(2) $$. So, the first entry, $0$, is the first coordinate of a vector in $\Bbb{C}^{4}$.

Comment: I still don't understand what is the value of fomula of $S$ in this case of $SU(2)$?

Comment: @OmarShehab The matrix you gave would be thought of as the vector $(0, -1, 1, 0)\in\Bbb{C}^4$. More generally, given
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & -\overline{\beta} \\ \beta & \overline{\alpha}
\end{pmatrix}\in SU(2),
$$
it corresponds to $(\alpha, -\overline{\beta}, \beta, \overline{\alpha})\in\Bbb{C}^4$. I'm not understanding what you mean "the value of formula of $S$." Do you mean the "S" in $SU(2)$, or the $S$ I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: it is the $S$ you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: I simply meant an arbitrary subset of $\Bbb{C}^{n^2}$. If we have such a subset, we can check whether or not it is dense in $SU(n)$ by simply seeing whether or not $\overline{S} = SU(n)$.